# How to dispose() the better_player when initialization

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, media-player

When opening a new page, the player continues to play this happens when I open another page at the moment the player is initializing

**Tried to dispose**

- when the focus on the widget disappeared
- when the button was pressed
- when the screen goes out of view

none of this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution.
At the moment the player is initialized, I block the route, after initialization I remove the lock and then you can go to another page by deleting the player.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose of your controller for the video player by calling `dispose()`:

```
  @override
      void dispose() {
        _videoController?.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
```

Substitute your controller name for `_videoController`.